# JSF 2 - @ManagedBean not detected

Tags: java, web-applications, jsf

I have a `ParentBean` class which has the [@ManagedBean](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/bean/ManagedBean.html) annotation. If I subclass this class, the `ChildBean` does not inherit the @ManagedBean annotation although the @ManagedBean annotation has the meta-annotation [Inherited](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html).

What am I missing ?

```
JSF 2.0
Mojarra 2.0.6 | JBoss 5.1.0.GA
Eclipse Indigo - Build id: 20110615-0604
```

**EDIT:** Still looking for a solution ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717376/how-does-jsf-find-beans-annotated-with-managedbean) and reading a little bit the source code from Mojarra (see [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717376/how-does-jsf-find-beans-annotated-with-managedbean)), I think Mojarra may not actually scan thoroughly the classes (for **loading performance**).

So my guess is that for one given class, the Mojarra `AnnotationScanner` stays on this class and it doesn't scan the hierarchy of this same class.

This is why my `ChildBean` is not recognized as a `ManagedBean`.

Answer (score 8):

`javax.annotation.ManagedBean` does not have `@Inherited`. `javax.faces.ManagedBean` has. Check your imports.

Furthermore, I wouldn't rely on that. I don't see it defined in the spec, but usually inheritance with jsf managed bean is a bad idea. Even if you have it, you should have an abstract base class that holds common functionality but is not a managed bean by itself.

Another thing - reading the code later on would be harder if you don't have the annotation on the bean. It may take a while until the reader realizes it is inherited.

So put `@ManagedBean` on each bean, and don't overuse inheritance.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I use `javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean`. This one is not inherited.

Comment: I'm using `javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean` to annotate `ParentBean`. `ChildBean` doesn't inherit this annotation.